# WIX CAQuietExec NETSH Command Fails

Tags: c#, wix, netsh

I would like my WIX Installer to quietly invoke a NETSH command to bind a self-signed certificate to an IP address:port.

The CAQuietExec is being invoked, but the NETSH command fails.

```
MSI (s) (C4:84) [16:19:50:455]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=customQtExecRtBindCertToPort,ActionType=3137,Source=BinaryData,Target=CAQuietExec,CustomActionData="netsh" http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8080 certhash=2B2C23C6B1334F886B9FFD827D64BDC072BBEFD7 appid={123456-7890-12345-4567-AAABBBCCCDDDFFFF})
MSI (s) (C4:8C) [16:19:50:457]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI87DB.tmp, Entrypoint: CAQuietExec
MSI (s) (C4:78) [16:19:50:457]: Generating random cookie.
MSI (s) (C4:78) [16:19:50:458]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 2588 (0xA1C).
MSI (s) (C4:38) [16:19:50:477]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (C4:38) [16:19:50:479]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Elevated custom action server.
CAQuietExec:  
CAQuietExec:  SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312
CAQuietExec:  A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
```

> A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

When I run the exact same command from a command shell, I am successful:

```
>SSL Certificate successfully added
```

My code is fairly simple:

```
    <CustomAction
        Id="customQtExecRtBindCertToPortData"
        Property="customQtExecRtBindCertToPort"
        Value="&quot;netsh&quot; http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:[RT_PORT] certhash=[CERT_THUMBPRINT] appid={123456-7890-12345-4567-AAABBBCCCDDDFFFF}"
        />
    <CustomAction 
        Id="customQtExecRtBindCertToPort" 
        BinaryKey="WixCA" 
        DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
        Execute="deferred" 
        Return="ignore" 
        Impersonate="no"
        />
```

I've tried running with elevated privileges in Windows Server 2008 R2, but still receive the same log output.

Answer (score 2):

In an attempt to revise my installer to call a custom Console application that, instead, calls NETSH under the hood (and some other tasks), I  arrived at what I believe was the actual issue.

While my CustomAction declaration has properties for Execute="deferred" and Impersonate="no" set correctly, I believe the install sequence at that time was not correctly defined to occur between **InstallInitialize** and **InstallFinalize**, as was stated in this link: [Installation change do not ask for UAC permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647697/installation-change-do-not-ask-for-uac-permissions).

Deploying to W2K12 with UAC and all that fun stuff, brought about the same error, then upon setting my custom action installer sequence to the following, I was able to over come the problem defined.

```
        <Custom
            Action="customQtExecRTBindCertToPortData"
            Before="InstallFinalize"
            >
            <![CDATA[NOT Installed AND CERTIFICATE_NEEDED = "TRUE" AND &featureServices = 3 ]]>
        </Custom>
        <Custom
            Action="customQtExecRTBindCertToPort"
            After="customQtExecRTBindCertToPortData"
            >
            <![CDATA[NOT Installed AND CERTIFICATE_NEEDED = "TRUE" AND &featureServices = 3 ]]>
        </Custom>
```