# How do I get WiX installer to request administrative privileges?

Tags: installation, wix, elevated-privileges

We have a program we have developed in house. We are upgrading to use Visual Studio 2012, and so have to leave the Visual Studio installer project behind. InstallShield LE was giving us problems with shortcuts if the application was already installed. This left me with finally going with WiX.

I have researched this for a few days and read several posts on how to get administrator rights, but none of them seem to work. The `Package` element has InstallPrivileges="1" and the following `Property` element is present:

```
<Property Id="MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION" Value="1" />
```

It will not request administrator privileges when it starts, and so it fails when it tries to create the program folder in `C:\Program Files(x86)`.

Comment: MSI does not request admin rights until the `InstallExecuteSequence`. To get admin rights from the beginning you would have to use a bootstrapper, look at the Burn Engine provided with WIX.

Comment: If your package installs per-machine, then MSI engine requests UAC elevation automatically. Could it be that your package is per-user but still tries to write to Program Files? Is `ALLUSERS` property set to 1?

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions.  To Natalie:  I cannot use a bootstrapper.  The output MUST be an MSI (someone else hard coded the upgrade link into the current app). I added the following, and I am not sure which (or what combination) gave me what I need, but it works now:

    `InstallPrivileges="elevated" AdminImage="yes" InstallScope="perMachine"`

Comment: @OpusKrokus You can post that as the answer, and accept it. In fact, I highly recommend you do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WiX installer should always run as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122282/wix-installer-should-always-run-as-administrator)

Comment: Check this: [WiX installer should always run as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49841229/775110)

Answer (score 30):

Answer on **How to get WiX installer to request Administrative Privileges**

Solution found by [Opus Krokus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1821388/opus-krokus) in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348156/how-to-get-wix-installer-to-request-administrative-privileges#comment20050114_14348156).

**Answer**

> I added the following (to the Package element), and I am not sure which (or what combination) gave me what I need, but it works now: InstallPrivileges="elevated" AdminImage="yes" InstallScope="perMachine"

Comment: I believe the right one is `InstallPrivileges`. I've removed the `AdminImage` attribute and my package is still requesting administrative privileges. `AdminImage` appears to mean another thing, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15434458/145349

Comment: Is it possible in `InstallScope="perUser"` ? I can not set elevated privileges for per user.

Comment: You will have to use `InstallScope="perMachine"` to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 commands:

```
<Property Id="MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION" Value="1" />     

<Condition Message="Installation requires Administrator privileges">
    <![CDATA[Privileged]]>
</Condition>
```

Observe that you must surround `Privileged` with `<![CDATA[`  and  `]]>`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the answer to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122282/wix-installer-should-always-run-as-administrator).

Here is the essence of the answer:

```
<Property Id="MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION" Value="1" />
```

The solution suggested by Opus Krokus did not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

This is what worked for me, for my MSI created for installation on Windows 7 (and later versions):

```
  <!-- Set per-machine installation as default.
  See See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408007.aspx for an explanation of ALLUSERS=2 and MSIINSTALLPERUSER="".
  -->
  <Property Id="ALLUSERS" Value="2" />
  <!-- Needs to be empty value (and empty value must be commented out to get rid of error message when compiling):
  <Property Id="MSIINSTALLPERUSER" Value="" /> 
  -->
```

As mentioned in the above XML-comment, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408007.aspx for details.