# .Net WFP install-able application for users, which DB can work without DB engine?

Tags: .net, database, wpf, windows-installer

I want to build a .Net WPF application for users, so they can install themselves. The application required a Database as well and want to add DB file in the installer. So user don't need to install separate DB engine. If any one install the  installer application everything will be ready for them. Which DB should I choose?

Comment: SQLite is a good option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with SQLite very light weight framework. Make sure you download and install an appropriate System.Data.SQLite setup package

Refer to the below link:

https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

Comment: I don't know much about **SQLite**, but I answered this question a while back on debugging its use after installation: [Relative path for SQLite not working with WIX Toolset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52323006/129130).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. DB size is fine for me just thinking about reliability and support. Planning to develop retail application for small business so data is important. Application targeted for  single user POS type and its windows native application.

Comment: Any idea about SQLite strength on ACID property, especially transactions - commit and roll back feature?