# Create installer with dependencies for x64 and x86

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, windows-installer, installation

I'm developing an application in C # that has several dependencies, one of which is different in 32 bits or 64 bits.

When I compile the application: [here is the result of the compilation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvAft.png)

In the x64 and x86 folders, the same dependency is found (SQLite.Interop.dll), but an architecture-specific file (x86: 1223 KB, x64: 1575 KB).

As said in the title, I want to create an installer for this application using Visual Studo Installer.

When I add the program output to "Application folder", all the dependencies come, except the one in the x64 or x86 folder. How can I add this famous dependency according to the architecture of the computer? If I have to create 2 different installers, how can I just add this dependency to each installer?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Bitness***: [**Different Packages are Required for Different Processor Architectures**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures.aspx). 64-Bit installers can install both 32-bit
>   and 64-bit components, 32-bit setups can only install 32-bit
>   components. 32-bit setups run on 64-bit systems, but 64-bit packages do not run on 32-bit systems. In other words you need two different installers, one for
>   32-bit and one for 64-bit.

***File Inclusion***: I don't use this project type (for reasons that will be clear below), but you should be able to add the file manually via **`Right Click Project => Add => File...`** and then compile two separate setups.

***Custom Actions***: Beware of bitness issues with custom actions when targeting different platforms. I usually build custom actions using 32-bit code.

---

***Deployment Tools***: [**There are some well-known limitations for Visual Studio Installer projects**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893/129130). Maybe have a quick look at [**other, common tools**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130) (terse summary of different deployment tools capabilities).

***Single Source***: [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com) does something fancy to allow targeting both architectures with one source. I am not quite sure what they do to be honest. [Installshield has similar constructs](https://blogs.flexera.com/installtalk/2011/01/building-32-bit-and-64-bit-installations-from-the-same-installshield-project/). WiX can use [compiler variables / preprocessor constructs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49501700/129130) (bottom) to achieve the same.

---

***Links***:

- ***Minimal WiX, Visual Studio Project***: [WiX installer msi not installing the Winform app created with Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970743/wix-installer-msi-not-installing-the-winform-app-created-with-visual-studio-2017/47972615#47972615) (just looking at the markup at the bottom with the inline comments is usually enough)
- ***Debug Session***: **[Relative path for SQLite not working with WIX Toolset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319558/relative-path-for-sqlite-not-working-with-wix-toolset/52323006#52323006)**