# Pre-requisites not installed using WIX bootstrapper in windows 10 OS

Tags: installation, wix, setup-deployment

I have created WIX setup for my application. I am bootstapping the prerequisites using WIX bootstapper. One of the prerequiste is to install SQL CE on the machine. 
The package install all the prerequisites for Window 7 OS, but for windows 10 OS it do not install the prerequisites.

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile=".\SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi"
                  Name="SQL Server Compact Edition 32bit"
                  Compressed="yes"
                  Vital="no"
                  Visible="yes"
                  Permanent="yes"
                  InstallCondition="VersionNT64"/> 
<MsiPackage  SourceFile =".\SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.msi"
                    Name="SQL Server Compact Edition 64bit"
                 Compressed ="yes"
                 Vital ="no"
                   ForcePerMachine="yes"
                 Permanent ="yes"
                   Visible="yes"
                  InstallCondition="VersionNT64"/>
```

I am not getting why it is not installing prerequisites in Win 10.

Comment: [SQL Server Compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) is a decrecated product. It is probably not officially supported on Windows 10? This OS is not listed under the ***"System Requirements"*** section here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29037

Comment: I wish I had a good "alternative" to suggest to you, but I don't have enough overview of database technology at the moment. There is [Sqlite](https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite). Hopefully Chris Painter will see this soon, he might have more details.

Comment: [Here is an answer on Sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319558/relative-path-for-sqlite-not-working-with-wix-toolset) - the only one I have ever looked at. Alternatively I suppose you can state that you don't support Windows 10? Sometimes possible in corporate scenarios - or there is a way to make it install just fine. Will test that when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

I think your version of **SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi** or **SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.msi** is not supported for windows 10.

Reference link for supported versions in Windows 10: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/is-microsoft-sql-ce-database-supported-in-windows/2edb9d8e-2fa1-42d6-b17b-7ebcbb672dba

You can try with **SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi** or **SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.msi** from the following website: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29037

Moreover, I found an issue with your code about **install condition** of **SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi**.
For 32 bit support, you should modify

```
InstallCondition="VersionNT64"
```

to

```
InstallCondition="NOT VersionNT64"
```

Reference url: [How to deploy 64-bit and a 32-bit Windows Installer package as a single setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147498/how-to-deploy-64-bit-and-a-32-bit-windows-installer-package-as-a-single-setup)