# WiX after installation my exe file doesn't work by double click, only run as administrator work

Tags: visual-studio, installation, wix

I prepare a MSI setup project with WiX when I install this MSI package to `%ProgramFiles%` and make a shortcut to desktop folder it is work only run as administrator. When double click it doesn't work. When I install folder in desktop it is work with double click. I want to install to `%ProgramFiles%` and work with double click. Please help me I spend 2 week for this installation.

my code is here.

```
<Product Id="*" Name="FlowNet Master" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.2" 
         Manufacturer="Melina-Aero" UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Platform='x64'  />

<Icon Id="icon.ico" SourceFile="Images\Splash Screen.jpg" />
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon.ico" />
<!--    <Property Id="MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION" Value="1" />-->

<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="Images\Banner.bmp" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="Images\Background.bmp" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="Licences\EULA.rtf" />
<Property Id="AllUSERS" Value="1"/>
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER2"/>
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>

<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
<MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
```

Answer (score 1):

***Elevated Rights***: Files installed under **`%ProgramFiles%`** will be **read-only** for standard users (and administrators as well, unless you elevate the rights via the **UAC prompt**). You must determine what your application is doing that requires write access to files installed under this folder - or whether you try to write to HKLM in the registry - which will cause the same problem (access denied exception). It is also possible that your application tries to do something that requires certain [NT Privileges](https://ss64.com/nt/ntrights.html) available only to admin users - causing elevation to be required (privileges differ from access rights - ACL - in being pervasive on the whole system, and not "attached" to objects - for example "change system time" - for lack of a better example).

***Move Files***: [**There are several ways to fix this access problem (or work around it)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50588465/129130), but few that are recommended. I would suggest you **move the settings file** that causes the exception to the user profile and store settings there with full write access. You can also **apply custom ACL permissions** to the installed files (see **section 6** in link above), but this is not a good idea for many reasons (safety, preservation of settings, etc...). See the link above for further descriptions of alternatives (store settings in database and access on launch and other approaches).

---

***Check List***: Here is [**a generic check list for application launch problems**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623588/windows-application-startup-error-exception-code-0xe0434352/49637913#49637913).

***Attach Debugger***: One technique I sometimes use is to install debug-binaries to **`%ProgramFiles%`** and then show a message box immediately from the launch sequence (if the launch gets that far at all). Then I attach the Visual Studio debugger to the message box and start interactive debugging from the installed product to check for errors and exceptions. [Procedure summarized here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52263983/wix-c-sharp-app-doesnt-launch-after-installing/52264406#52264406).

> **Disclaimer**: Though obvious, it has to be mentioned: **never use debug binaries for actual release**. **`1)`** Not at all legal, **`2)`** not a good idea due to the transparency
>   and reverse-engineering possibilities of debug binaries, and **`3)`** debug runtime binaries will not exist on non-developer boxes (and don't be tempted to statically link - if that is possible in debug mode). And finally: it
>   could be easy to forget to rebuild with release binaries when you mess
>   around with debugging like this. It sure happens.

***Dependency Scan***: There are a number of tools you can use to scan for dependency problems that can cause launch problems. [Here is a dependency scanning tools list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939079/which-winform-project-files-should-be-packed-up-into-the-installer/51940598#51940598). Maybe also check the section "*Visual Studio Modules View*". I am not sure if that view would show you what settings files are in use (or just what binaries are loaded).

---

***Some Links***:

- [wix service install not enough permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768425/wix-service-install-not-enough-permission/51775803#51775803)