# How check UAC (admin rights) in WIX v4 Installer?

Tags: uac, wix4

I didn't work with WIX Installer. Now I work with latest WIX v4.
I want to check with which rights was started installer and after this dynamically select the installation path.

Idea example:

```
if is_admin()
    StandardDirectory Id="ProgramFiles6432Folder"
else
    StandardDirectory Id="LocalAppDataFolder"
```

I see these steps:

1. User see UAC prompt
2. User Click Yes or No
3. Here I try to understand execution level

How can I do this?

I tried to find information how to do it and found that I can use Privileged property but I not found any example of code on WIX v4... Or maybe on WIX v3

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get WiX installer to request administrative privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348156/how-do-i-get-wix-installer-to-request-administrative-privileges)

Comment: That's not the way it works. You don't check admin rights, you just request them and then it's up to the user to provide them. See suggested duplicate.

Comment: @PalleDue thanks for answer but I don't need to Request admin rights. Installer can be executed in silent mode so I need to understand execution level on the fly...
1) User see UAC prompt
2) User Click Yes or No
3) Here I try to understand execution level

Can I do this?

Comment: @PalleDue, I have a question - Can I reach my goal through Custom Action?  For example I write plugin DLL on C# which realize function is_admin() which exexutes on the fly.  Thank you for your help

Comment: That's one way to do it, but not easy.

Comment: @PalleDue that answer uses wix toolset v3, the question is about v4