# Wix - Can't set InstallScope to perMachine

Tags: wix, installation, admin

I set InstallScope="perMachine" and InstallPrivileges="elevated" in "Package" but still my installaer crush beacouse of user right which I need in one of Custom action.

In installation log file I found

> Running product '{C4827DAA-A2A2-4158-A423-010A6183D50D}' with user privileges: It's not assigned.

when I run installer with admin rights I have

> Running product '{0C0539DB-8422-465C-97DC-A696A7A5D51A}' with elevated privileges: Product is assigned.

How can I force to run installer only with admin rights?

Comment: This looks pretty similar to your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122282/wix-installer-should-always-run-as-administrator. Have you tried that workaround?

Comment: Yes, I also set this property (MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION) but nothing changes.

Comment: In that custom action, use `Execute="deferred"` and `Impersonate="no"`.

Comment: but in some custome actions I need to change something in system like add AppPool to IIS so I can't do this.